# Strange behaviour of BIT(64) column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me understand the following problem with a BIT(64) column in MySQL (5.7.19).

This simple example works fine and returns the record from the temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (v bit(64));
INSERT INTO test values (b'111');
SELECT * FROM test WHERE v = b'111';
-- Returns the record as expected
```

When using all the 64 bits of the column it no longer works:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (v bit(64));
INSERT INTO test values (b'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111');
SELECT * FROM test WHERE v = b'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';
-- Does NOT return the record
```

This only happens when using a value with 64 bits. But I would expect that to be possible.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Please do not respond by advising me not to use BIT columns. I am working on a database tool that should be able to handle all the data types of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that the value `b'11..11'` in the WHERE clause is considered to be a `SIGNED BIGINT` which is `-1` and is compared to the value in your table which is considered to be an `UNSIGNED BIGINT` which is `18446744073709551615`. This is always an issue when the first of 64 bits is `1`. IMHO this is a bug or a design flaw, because I expect an expression in the WHERE clause to match a row if the same expression has been used in the INSERT satement (at least in this case).

One workaround would be to cast the value to `UNSIGNED`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE v = CAST(b'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111' as UNSIGNED);
```

Or (if your application language supports it) convert it to something like `long uint` or `decimal`:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE v = 18446744073709551615;
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for your reply. I agree that it seems like a bug, but it is probably "by design". Anyway, your suggestion of casting the value as unsigned solved it for me and it can be used both when inserting data and in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Bits are returned as binary, so to display them, either add 0, or use a function such as HEX, OCT or BIN to convert them https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/bit/ or Bit values in result sets are returned as binary values, which may not display well. To convert a bit value to printable form, use it in numeric context or use a conversion function such as BIN() or HEX(). High-order 0 digits are not displayed in the converted value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-value-literals.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is not displaying the value but that it does not work in the WHERE clause (see accepted answer).